# Calculus trig right angle intersect

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Q:Find $a>0$ so that the curves $y=\sin(ax)$ and $y=\cos(ax)$ intersect at right angles.

I took derivative of both ,than $a^2\cos(ax)(-\sin(ax))=-1$  i multiplied both side by 2 so,
$sin(2ax)=$$\frac{2}{a^2}$

And since, $-1<sin<1$

$-1<$$\frac{2}{a^2}$$<1$ and $\frac{2}{a^2 }$ already pozitive so $0<$$\frac{2}{a^2}$$<1$ 
My answer is $a>$$\sqrt{2}$

Is it true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The curves cross when $x=\frac\pi{4a}+k\frac\pi a$, with $k\in\mathbb Z$. At such point, the slope of the tangent of $\sin(ax)$ is $(-1)^k\frac a{\sqrt2}$ and the slope of the tangent of $\cos(ax)$ is $(-1)^{k+1}\frac a{\sqrt2}$. The product of this two numbers is $-1$ (that is, the lines intersect at a right angle) when (and only when) $a=\sqrt2$.